# alert on child load

Tags: javascript, window.open

I want to open a window with `window.open` and attach a function to it's `onload`.
forexample, when child page load completed (just DOM), browser shows an alert in child page.
This code doesn't work::

```
var google;
function google(){
    google = window.open('http://www.google.com/');

    // Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

    /* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
    if (google.document.addEventListener){
        google.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoaded, false);
    }

    /* for Internet Explorer */
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_win32)
        google.document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
        var script = google.document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            pageLoaded(); // call the onload handler
        }
        };
    /*@end @*/

    /* for Safari */
    if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){ // sniff
        var _timer = setInterval(function(){
            if (/loaded|complete/.test(google.document.readyState)) {
                pageLoaded(); // call the onload handler
            }
        }, 10);
    }

    google.onload = pageLoaded;
}
function pageLoaded(){
    alert('Loading Completed');
}
```

Comment: Same-Origin-Policy. You cannot modify the code of a foreign-domain document - or even inject scripts into it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var google;
function googleload()
{
    google = window.open('http://www.google.com/');

    // Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

    /* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
    if (google.document.addEventListener)
    {
            google.window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
                alert('Loading Completed');
            }, false);
    }
    else
    {
        google.window.onload = function(){ //Add window.onload
            alert('Loading Completed');
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the same origin policy is in your way

Here is what I would try if I really had to

```
function popAndAlert(url) {
  var w = window.open('','mywindow');
  if (w) {
    w.document.write('<body onload="opener.done()">'+
      '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+url+'"></iframe></body>')
    w.document.close();
  }
}
function done() {
  alert('loading completed');
}
```

to alert in the child page, change

```
onload="opener.done()"
```

to

```
onload="alert('loading complete')"
```